# Change the text of Header attribute of collapse when clicking it. (Antd)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm new to Antd. I would like to change the header text from "show details" to "hide details" when you click on it. The header is part of the collapse feature in Antd. I have attached two images of what I want to do along with the code I currently have.

```
<Collapse
              bordered={false}
              className="shadow p-2 mb-5 bg-white rounded
              style={{ marginTop: 16, width: '100%', background: 'white' }}
              >
                <Collapse.Panel header="Show Details">
                  <table border={0} cellPadding={5} cellSpacing={10}>
                    <tr>
                      <th className="table-header">Lead Information</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Lead Owner</td>
                      <td>
                        <input className="inputField-2" type="text" />
                      </td>
                      <td>Company</td>
                      <td>
                        <input className="inputField-2" type="text" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td>Twitter</td>
                      <td>
                        <input className="inputField-2" type="text" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <br />
                </Collapse.Panel>
</Collapse>
```

[show details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS3es.png)

[hide details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YOiX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Antd Collapse may not have an API for this, so you can use useState hook to save state when clicking on Collapse.Panel. Then use that state to check which header to display.

```
const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
     
<Collapse
  onChange={(key) =>
    key.length > 0 ? setCollapsed(false) : setCollapsed(true)
  }
>
  <Collapse.Panel
    key={"detail"}
    header={collapsed ? "Show Detail" : "Hide Detail"}
  >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </Collapse.Panel>
</Collapse>
```

If you have multiple Collapse.Panel, remember to check the condition for each panel.